# Authenticate user login code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, model, controller

I am currently able to allow a user to login and the login form has validation rules to make sure the fields are not empty, HOWEVER... if any random name or letters are typed into the fields the user is logged in. How can I stop this and only allow actual users in the database to be logged in? My model and controller are below

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('login_model');
    }


    public function index()
    {
         if(($this->session->userdata('username')!=""))
         {
             $this->welcome();
         } else {
             $data['title']= 'MVC Application';
             $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
             $this->load->view('templates/nav');
             $this->load->view('login/signin', $data);
             $this->load->view('templates/footer');
         }
    }


    public function welcome()
    {

        $data['title']= 'MVC Application';
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/nav');
        $this->load->view('login/welcome', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }


    public function login()
    {
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $password=$this->input->post('pass');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'password', 'trim|required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->index();
        } else {
            $this->login_model->login($email,$password);
            $this->welcome(); 
        } 
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $newdata = array(
                 'id'   =>'',
                 'username'  =>'',
                 'email'     => '',
                 'logged_in' => FALSE,
                );
        $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata );
        session_destroy();
        redirect('login/index');
    }

    function update() {

        if(!empty($_POST)) {

            // Form submitted -- update database
            $data = array (
                   'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                   'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                   'password' => $this->input->post('password')
                  );
            $this->load->model('login_model');
            $this->login_model->update($data);
            redirect('login/welcome');

        } else {

            // Display form
            // Prepare data to pass to the view
            $data = array (
                      'title' => 'MVC Application',
                      'username' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
                      'email' => $this->session->userdata('email'),
                      'password' => $this->session->userdata('password')
                     );

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/nav');
            $this->load->view('login/update', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }

    }
}
?>
```

Model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
            $this->load->database();
    }

    public function login($email, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where("email",$email);
        $this->db->where("password",$password);
        $query=$this->db->get("mvc_user");

        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $rows)
        {
        //add all data to session
        $newdata = array(
                   'id'  => $rows->id,
                   'username'  => $rows->username,
                   'email'    => $rows->email,
                   'password' => $rows->password,
                   'logged_in'  => TRUE,
                  );
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function update($data) {
    $my_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    if($my_id !== false) { // Just making sure we're logged in
        $this->db->where('id', $my_id);
        $this->db->update('mvc_user', $data); 
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: can clear bit more ??? Edit question with what you need

Comment: I just need only users that are in the database to be able to logged in. Say someone tries to log in without their details in the database, I would like an error to display and say they cannot log in, whereas at the moment anyone will log in and it creates a session with empty credentials @Abdulla

Comment: Now I have sensibly indented your code at least one error should be **shouting at you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model. change the login function to:

```
public function login($email, $password)
{
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $this->db->where('password',$password);
    $query = $this->db->get('mvc_user');

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            //add all data to session
            $newdata = array(
                'id'        => $row->id,
                'username'  => $row->username,
                'email'     => $row->email,
                'password'  => $row->password,
                'logged_in' => TRUE,
            );
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your controller login:

```
public function login()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('pass');

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    // field name, error message, validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'password', 'trim|required');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() && $this->login_model->login($email, $password)) { //If success login
        $this->welcome();
        //Here we can echo success because both the form validation was successfull and the login. 
    } else {
        $this->index();
        //Here goes the Error message
    }
}
```

You can also use `$query = $this->db->get_where('mvc_user', array('email' => $email, 'password', $password));`

instead of

```
$this->db->where('email',$email);
$this->db->where('password',$password);
$query = $this->db->get('mvc_user');
```

if you prefer short code

Comment: I did this and got an error 'Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::num_rows()

Filename: models/Login_model.php

Line Number: 18' @IlanHasanov

Comment: thanks @IlanHasanov! where would I place my error message?

Comment: @Jess see the comments i just left now. Glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

In your Login action instead of just:

```
$this->login_model->login($email,$password);
$this->welcome();
```

You have to check if its true or false

```
if($this->login_model->login($email,$password)) {
    $this->welcome();
} else {
    // HERE is the place for wrong user/pass message to be triggered
}
```

2nd thing..
Remove any session update from your UPDATE and Login methods inside the user model. And instead add another method and call it from both login and update..

```
private function setSessionData($userid){
    $this->db->where('user_id', $userid);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($row = $query->row()){
        $newdata = array(
            'id'  => $rows->id,
            'username'  => $rows->username,
            'email'    => $rows->email,
            'password' => $rows->password,
            'logged_in'  => TRUE,
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This way you will have an easier way to set session data from different places..